# Airflow initdb failed in Amazon Linux

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, airflow, python-2.x

I am trying to install Airflow in EC2 (Amazon Linux) and "airflow initdb" fails with the following error:

```
$ AIRFLOW_HOME=/var/lib/airflow airflow initdb
[2019-09-07 20:51:32,416] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/airflow", line 22, in <module>
    from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 68, in <module>
    from airflow.www_rbac.app import cached_app as cached_app_rbac
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/app.py", line 26, in <module>
    from flask_appbuilder import AppBuilder, SQLA
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .base import AppBuilder
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .api.manager import OpenApiManager
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from marshmallow_sqlalchemy.fields import Related, RelatedList
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .schema import TableSchemaOpts, ModelSchemaOpts, TableSchema, ModelSchema
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 101
    class TableSchema(ma.Schema, metaclass=TableSchemaMeta):
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Since this is a syntax error, I suspect there is some version conflict between marshmallow_sqlalchemy and SQLAlchemy. Here are their versions:

```
apache-airflow==1.10.5
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.0
marshmallow==2.20.3
marshmallow-enum==1.5.1
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.19.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.8
```

Any idea?

Comment: Looks like you're running Python 3 code in 2.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

looks like the marshmallow-sqlalchemy version has upgraded, that is why you are getting this error. Uninstall the current version-

**pip uninstall marshmallow-sqlalchemy**

and try installing the below version, and then you should be good to go.

**pip install marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.17.1**

I was also facing the similar issue but now it is resolved in the same way.
**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Marshmallow-SQLAlchemy 0.18.0 was the last release to support Python 2.7: https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-sqlalchemy/blob/dev/CHANGELOG.rst